# Is it possible to estimate the sign of real part of eigenvalues of a 10 by 10 matrix only by observing all the entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I have a symbolic 10 by 10 matrix. It is not difficult to get the eigenvalue expressions by using Matlab. But the expressions of some eigenvalues are too long to be analyzed. I was wondering if there is a way to analyze the sign of real part of eigenvalues only by observing the matrix since all the entry expressions are pretty simple?

The matrix is like this:
\begin{bmatrix}  -k_1-p_1\lambda & 0 &0 &0 & 0 &0 &0 &-\lambda^2p_1 &0 &0\\
                 0 &  -k_2-p_2\lambda & a_{13}\omega &0 & 0 &0 &0 &0 &-\lambda^2p_2 &0 \\
0  &a_{12}\omega & -k_3-p_3\lambda &0 & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0  &-\lambda^2p_3\\
-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &0 &-\frac{\omega}{2} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
\frac{\cos{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &\frac{\omega}{2} &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &\frac{\cos{\theta}}{2} &-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{\omega}{2}&0 &0 &0\\
0 &\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} &\frac{\cos{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &-\frac{\omega}{2}&0 &0 &0 &0\\
-1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-\lambda &0 &0\\
0 &-1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &-\lambda &0 \\
0 &0 &-1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0  &-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}.

Thanks.

Comment: If the matrix is triangular it's easy to find the eigenvalues. Other than that I wouldn't expect to be able to tell much just by looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the rows and columns in the order $1,8,4,5,2,3,9,10,6,7$. Your matrix is permutation-similar to the direct sum of
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
-k_1-p_1\lambda  &-\lambda^2p_1 &0 &0\\
-1 &-\lambda &0 &0\\
\hline
-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &-\frac{\omega}{2}\\
\frac{\cos{\theta}}{2} &0 &\frac{\omega}{2} &0\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc|cc}
-k_2-p_2\lambda & a_{13}\omega &-\lambda^2p_2 &0 &0 &0\\
a_{12}\omega & -k_3-p_3\lambda &0  &-\lambda^2p_3 &0 &0\\
-1 &0 &-\lambda &0 &0 &0\\
0 &-1 &0 &-\lambda &0 &0\\
\hline
\frac{\cos{\theta}}{2} &-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{\omega}{2}\\
\frac{\sin{\theta}}{2} &\frac{\cos{\theta}}{2} &0 &0 &-\frac{\omega}{2}&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
The eigenvalues of the three $2\times2$ subblocks should be easy to analyse. It remains to find the eigenvalues of the $4\times4$ subblock of $B$.

Comment: Are you using elementary row operations?

Comment: @facebook-1536745818 Not exactly. Permute the rows **and** columns simultaneously, and you get a block-lower-triangular matrix.

Comment: Do you mean permute 1st row and column with 8th row and column simultaneously first and etc? Will this not change the original eigenvalues? Thanks.

Comment: @facebook-1536745818 Yes, that's what I mean. Eigenvalues of a matrix are invariant under similarity transform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It inspires me.